# Deleting a node in a linked list C++

Tags: c++

So I'm having a hard time getting this to work, and even after extensive googling I can't quite get it to work. Here's the function I'm working on :

```
bool deleteOneOf(const std::string & target)
{
    Node * ptr = _first;
    Node * temp;
    while (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        if (target != ptr->_entry)
        {
            temp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->_link;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->_link = ptr->_link;
            delete ptr->_link;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The Node class I have to work with is this:

```
class Node
{
public:
    std::string _entry;
    Node * _link;

    Node(std::string entry, Node * link) : _entry(entry), _link(link)
    {}
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized temp.  If you are looking at the first element in the list, it will point to garbage.  Also, you need to delete ptr.  Fixed code:

```
bool deleteOneOf(const std::string & target)
{
    Node * ptr = _first;
    Node * temp = nullptr;
    while (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        if (target != ptr->_entry)
        {
            temp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->_link;
        }
        else
        {
            if (temp)
                temp->_link = ptr->_link;
            else
                _first = ptr->_link;
            delete ptr;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I have one question further I guess, it's on this bit of code: if(temp). If temp = nullptr, does that statement just not get evaluated?

Comment: if (temp) is the same thing as if (temp != nullptr).